# Prevent anonymous to input a registered email during commerce checkout through Rules?

Tags: rules, commerce

In Drupal Commerce, how to prompt a warning message and keep it in `checkout` process if an anonymous inputs a registered email? I know there is a `Commerce Checkout Login`, but it is just an AJAX addon.

I believe I can do it through Rules and that's what I did.

- Event: Process checkout pane
- Conditions:

  - Data comparison: [commerce-order:uid] == 0
  - NOT Data value is empty: [commerce-order:mail]
  - Entity exists by property: User/Email, [commerce-order:mail]
- Actions:

  - Show a message on the site: Warning, ...
  - Update checkout status: checkout

In first trial, it seems work well. But the weird thing is, when I change the email field to an unregistered one, I can still spot the warning message generated by `Show a message on the site`. Is there something wrong in my rule setup?

Refer to this [Anonymous can use registered email address: intended behavior?](https://drupal.org/node/1469946).

Comment: Are you sure that commerce isn't creating user profiles upon checkout?  Some implementations do that for anonymous users...

Comment: Yes, it does. But what I am looking for is to prevent the creation of user profiles when anonymous inputs a registered email. Otherwise, anonymous can create an order. Refer for to https://drupal.org/node/1469946, what I exactly like to solve.

Comment: You mentioned `Commerce checkout login` it will solve that issue by allowing the user to login if they enter a registered email address.

Comment: `Commerce checkout login` does that job well. But anonymous can just ignore it and keep the checkout, which is what I like to prevent.

Comment: This isn't an answer, so I'll just leave it as a comment: I wouldn't do this during Rules. What you want is form validation, not really form post-processing. Why not just hook into this form with hook_form_alter() and make it do exactly what you want without having to work around Rules?

Comment: @RyanSzrama, thanks a lot for reminding this. I am about to check if I can code out a module with workable form validation then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @RyanSzrama's suggestion, I pursue a form validation solution. What I finally use is to implement a `hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter`. The following is a simplified code snippet for that.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter
 */
function MYMODULE_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter(&$checkout_panes) {
  if(isset($checkout_panes['account'])){
    $checkout_panes['account']['callbacks']['checkout_form_validate'] = 'MYMODULE_form_validate';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_form_validate($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
    $mail = $form['account']['login']['mail']['#value'];
    $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE mail = '%s';", $mail);
    if (db_query($query)->fetchField()) {
      $msg = t('The email address is registered to an account!');
      form_set_error('[account][login][mail]', $msg);
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Hope that also provides some hint or help to others. For form validation, please refer to [Adding validation to commerce pane form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87060/adding-validation-to-commerce-pane-form).