# Required field set via hook_form_alter not fully working in Commerce Checkout form

Tags: entities, commerce

I created a hook function to make a field **required** and **visible**. The targeted form is the Checkout Billing Form at: example.com/en/checkout/35

I have to mention that the site is build with the Commerce Kickstart distribution.

```
        <?php
    function MyModule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
            if ($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {  
                    $form['customer_profile_billing']['field_cif_nif_id']['#states'] = array(
                      // This #states rule says that the "field_cif_nif_id" fieldset should only
                      // be VISIBLE and REQUIRED if the "field_dispongo_de_" form element is set to "CIF/NIF/ID".
                              'visible' => array(
                                    '#edit-customer-profile-billing-field-dispongo-de-und' => array('value' => t('CIF/NIF/ID')),
                            ),'required' => array(
                                    '#edit-customer-profile-billing-field-dispongo-de-und' => array('value' => t('CIF/NIF/ID')),
                            ),
                    );

                   $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; //THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING
      }
    } 
    ?>
```

The function seems to work fine since the fied is marked with the red asterisk *, but it is not really working since the form is sent and saved even if the required field is empty.

I think the problem is not in the function but in its relation with the Commerce Checkout form provided by Drupal Commerce or Commerce Kickstart.

Comment: try $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
I am guessing.

Comment: Have you seen this post: [Required elements buggy with #states](https://www.drupal.org/node/1017882)

Comment: @IsraelMorales I added the line (you can see it in the function now). But, not working at all.

Comment: @J.Reynolds I'll read it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `required` along with `#states` will add the required indicator to the element, But there will be **no** client or server side validation involved. So to make the field as required you would have to add the custom validation to the form and there you can validate the field something like below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MODULE-NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check if the form is commerce checkout form.
  if ($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
    // Add the custom validation function to the form.
    $form['buttons']['continue']['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_custom_validate_required_field';
  }
}

/**
 * Callback handling the custom validation.
 */
function mymodule_custom_validate_required_field($form, &$form_state) {
  // Check if the field you want to validate exists in the form.
  // replace 'field_dispongo_de_' with the name of field you want to validate.
  if ((isset($form_state['values']['field_dispongo_de_'])) && (empty($form_state['values']['field_dispongo_de_']))) {
    form_set_error('field_dispongo_de_', 'Field cannot be left blank');
  }
}
```

---

**Alternate way:**

Since its a commerce checkout form so we can add the custom validation using [hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info/DC) and [commerce_checkout_form_validate](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!checkout!includes!commerce_checkout.pages.inc/function/commerce_checkout_form_validate/7) as discussed here: [Adding validation to commerce pane form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87060/adding-validation-to-commerce-pane-form)

Comment: not working. The field to be validated is `$form['customer_profile_billing']['field_cif_nif_id']`

Comment: @chefnelone In that case you would have to replace `field_dispongo_de_` with `field_cif_nif_id` at all the places in above solutions, also you may debug the things using `dpm($VARIABLE-NAME);`

Comment: That's is what I did, but it doesn't fix the problmem

Comment: http://pastebin.com/06HN1m42

Comment: You need to check the form values u(using `dpm`) inside `utilities_custom_validate_required_field`function, something like `dpm($form_state['values'])` and in that check what is the exact name of the field we want to validate and that you can replace in `if` condition.

Comment: I tried, but I can't get to see any output for dpm(). I tried with dpm('Hello') and nothing. Maybe the cause is that it is a multi-step form..??

Comment: @chefnelone if its a multi-step than you can check the form values on submitting the complete form and from there you can come to know what is the exact name of the field to validate.

Comment: I can't get the output of dpm(). It's seems like `function mymodule_custom_validate_required_field($form, &$form_state) {` is not executed at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17498/discussion-between-ankit-agrawal-and-chefnelone).